# The right border of my tables doesn't end at the border of my last column

Tags: html, css

My right side table border goes way further then the last column(The light grey line is my border), see the image below:
[image]

This is the css code of the table:

```
        table.tableizer-table {
            font-size: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
```

The td and th, see below:

```
        .tableizer-table td {
            padding: 4px;
            margin: 3px;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
        }

        .tableizer-table th {
            background-color: #1e73be;
            color: #FFF;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Html:

```
<table style="display:none;" class="tableizer-table" id="tableMonths">
```

This is what i do in JS:

```
document.getElementById('tableMonths').style.display = 'block';
```

Does any one knows why this problem occurs?

Comment: Could you give the html too?

Comment: share your html code too

Comment: Please share your html

Comment: provide your html code and generate code snippet here in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have 'display: block' on the table somewhere else in your code, which is making it take up the full width. Try inspecting it and changing the value to 'inline'.

Comment: this could very well be the issue, would still be nice to see the html do

Comment: Okay, let me try it